# In nginx logs: SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:required cipher missing

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls

We disabled SSLv3 several months ago, and on Sunday I noticed this filling our nginx logs. It's been continuing ever since and users are emailing us saying they cannot connect to our site.

```
2015/01/13 13:55:39 [crit] 14596#0: 1154120 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0D7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:required cipher missing) while SSL handshaking, client: *.*.*.*, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Neither I or anybody on our support team can reproduce it. We haven't made any recent changes on our end that would impact SSL negotiation.

Has anybody ever seen this before? Googling "openssl required cipher missing" doesn't return much. The only thing I've found so far that relates directly to the issue is [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=951156) bugzilla  issue, which appears to have died in discussion. Several users have replied back to say they're using FireFox, but one other said they are using IE. They could be mistaken, however.

Comment: As that bug report noted, the user's antivirus is the prime suspect. But you do not mention having checked this.

Comment: All users except one claim that they're on Android using FireFox or the stock browser. I wonder if there's a known bug that's making browsers get stuck on trying to use SSLv3. Anybody know of anything?